# Principle of Math Induction - [P(n+1) is true regardless of P(n)]

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

In class, we learned that for a sequence of logical statements $(P(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, if (1) $P(1)$ is true and (2) $[P(n)\implies{P(n+1)}]$, we can say that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, P(n)$ is true.

I am trying to use the principle of mathematical induction on a problem: $P(n)=[x_n > \text{constant}]$

So far, I have proved $P(1)$ to be true. Now, I am trying to show that $[P(n)\implies{P(n+1)}]$, but rather than using $P(n)$ to show $P(n+1)= \text{true}$, I used another known fact about the $x_n$ to show that $P(n+1)$ is true. *i.e.,* $P(n)$ was not used at all to determine $P(n+1) =\text{true}$ (but I've definitely shown it's true).

Can I still use the Principle of Mathematical Induction to draw a conclusion in stating $P(n)=\text{true}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Instead of using induction, you have proven $P(n)$ is true for all $n$ by choosing an arbitrary $n$ and thence proving the statement. So, this is not a proof by induction.

Comment: it may still be a valid proof of the fact, though...

Comment: Well, technically you can still write a proof by induction (assume $P(n)$. Now prove $P(n+1)$, thus proving the necessary implication), but it is very unnecessary. Removing the induction parts would give a direct, shorter and clearer proof.

Comment: If the proof of $P(n+1)$ doesn't also work for $P(1)$, you can just write the proof as "Case 1: $n=1$ ... Case 2: $n>1$ ... Therefore $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 1$.